# Spain: Convert cash to electronic money?

Tags: banking, cash, electronic-payment, spain

I am in Spain, have some cash, and would like to move that to a German bank account. I asked at Deutsche Bank Spain, and they said that to do that, I would need an account at their bank.

Note that while I do have a Deutsche Bank account, it's at Deutsche Bank Germany which is separate from Deutsche Bank Spain.

Anyhow: *In Spain, how do I convert cash to electronic money?*

I simply write *electronic money*, since moving cash to PayPal or to my credit card would do as well. From there, I could send it to any bank account, either directly or via detours.

## Update

I just got a reply from Deutsche Bank:

> Im Ausland können Sie nur per Überweisung Geld auf Ihr Konto übertragen. Ob Banken vor Ort Bareinzahlungen für ein Konto in Deutschland machen, können wir leider nicht beurteilen. Dies müssten Sie bitte in Spanien erfragen.

My translation:

> From foreign countries, you can only transfer money to your bank account by remittance. Whether banks in Spain allow cash deposits to your account in Germany, we are not able to say. Please ask in Spain.

Comment: Am I right in assuming, you don't have a bank account in Spain ?? Or you don't want to use your current bank

Comment: @DumbCoder I do not have a bank account in Spain.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would simply find a friendly local who is willing to Paypal you for cash.

Comment: That's certainly an option. I hope, though, that there is a way which doesn't make me depend on a local.

Answer (score 2):

You could buy a money order with your cash, then mail the money order to Deutsche Bank Germany for deposit into your account.

You could also buy a prepaid debit card (like a Visa/AMEX giftcard) with your cash. Then, open a new Paypal account and add this prepaid card. Finally, send money to yourself using the prepaid card as the funding source.

You could use a money transfer service, like Western Union, to transfer the cash to a friend/family in Germany. Then ask them to deposit it for you at Deutsche Bank Germany.

Comment: Concerning sending a money order to my bank: I would have to double check that. I like the idea with the prepaid card / voucher, if some such thing is available in Spain. Western Union, etc.: No, because then I could as well ask someone in Spain, and it's expensive.

Comment: I guess for filing a money order, I would need a bank account in Spain.

Comment: Can't you buy a money order at Western Union? Does the Spanish post office sell money orders? Banks are not the only places that sell money orders in the US. I'm assuming Spain is similar.

Comment: Yes, the Spanish post (Correos) does offer [money orders to Germany](http://www.correos.es/contenido/03P-EnviarDinero/01-Giro/04-GiroInternacional/03P0102-GiroInternacional.asp). The question is: How I make the order go directly into my bank account?

Comment: You have to mail the money order to your bank. Include a deposit slip if you have one, if not write a note on a slip of paper stating you want it deposited into your account and include your account number.

Comment: Endorse the money order with "FOR DEPOSIT ONLY - Deutsche Bank Germany" and include your account number on the money order. Do not sign an endorsement. Send it to any branch - its just like using the night drop depository.

Comment: Thanks! However, I should check with my bank first how to do it in Germany, and if that is possible at all. In addition to a bank account number, I certainly would need to specify the [BLZ](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bankleitzahl).